# inserting into multiple related table at once and return id if exists else insert into multiple tables

Tags: database, postgresql

I am a newbie to SQL/PostgreSQL. I wanted to insert into multiple related tables at once if certain criteria is satisfied else return the existing id of the table. Let me give an example here, following are my exemplary tables.

```
CREATE TABLE profile (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE movies (
    movied_id serial NOT NULL,
    movie_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    profile_id INTEGER NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profile.id  
)

CREATE TABLE sports (
    sport_id serial NOT NULL,
    sport_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    profile_id INTEGER NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (sport_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profile.id  
)

CREATE TABLE visited_countries (
    country_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    profile_id INTEGER NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (country_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profile.id  
)
```

Here, profile table contains id, first_name, last_name and it is related to movies, sports, visited_countries tables.  There exist one to many relation ship between the  profile table and all the other tables (Foreign Keys are shown in tables as well). Given this situation:

1. I want to insert into all these tables at once in the order by getting the unique profile ID first and then use that as FK for all the other tables.
2. I wanted to check the following before inserting into all of them.
   -- first_name, last_nane, and all the movies, sports, visited_countries seen by profile id should be different then only I will insert into all these table at once in the order using the generated profiled ID else just return the profile id.
3. I have multiple clients writing into the tables at the same time so I wanted to lock and do this transaction in one go.

I read couple of things using CTEs but couldn't get it working correctly. Any suggestion and systematic approach to do this would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you should choose your database first.

Comment: mydatabase is postgres:-)